# How to send tweet to twitter with jquery inside my site

Tags: jquery, tweets

There is MANY API and script and plugin out there to get feed, hash tag and tweet from twitter. I like to SEND tweet TO twitter from my site with jquery

something like

```
$('#somebutton').click( function (){

var text='some intelligent things to say';
#.twitit(text);

})
```

it's it something possible ?

now i use :

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="vertical">Tweet it</a></div>
```

but that take the title of the page to send it to twitter.. not really what i want !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="Something other than page title" data-count="vertical">Tweet it</a></div>
```

You can even set it dynamically via:

```
$('.twitter-share-button').attr('data-text', 'Some text to tweet');
```

**UPDATE:** If you're just trying to use your own Twitter button, you can simply use web intents, Twitter's fancy way of saying "regular old URLs". See: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=[your URL]&text=[some text to tweet]
```

Since it's part of a URL, make sure you urlencode all the parameters.

Comment: it's a big fugly button... not like the one i design ! but thanks i learn one thing !

Comment: the https: part of the answer is WAY MORE what i ask !.. thanks

Comment: It's not a button at all. It's an anchor.

Answer (score 0):

here is some sample code i have found...
I still have the big ugly twitter button  !

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[data-text]').each(function(){
      $(this).attr('data-text', "This works!");
    });
    $.getScript('http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js');
});
</script>

<a href="http://twitter.com/share"
    class="twitter-share-button"
    data-text="This is what we want to change dynamically"
    data-count="none" data-via="chris_camps">Tweet</a>
<!-- moved to the js above <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script> -->
```